# Windows XP MBR as a file

Tags: virtualbox, mbr

I would like to start a Windows XP installation in a VirtualBox VM from a physical partition. For this I need the Windows XP MBR as a file. Can anybody read this out and upload it for me?

If somebody has access to a Linux machine, this is one way to do it:

```
sudo apt-get install mbr
install-mbr WindowsXP.mbr --force
```

Many thanks!

Comment: There are more appropriate forums for asking things like this. SuperUser, I think, is more about asking questions, not asking to deliver data, no matter what that data might be.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just run a Linux LiveCD in that VirtualBox and do it yourself ?
You already have all the tools you need and know how to do it.

Comment: I don't have a LiveCD available and my internet connection is too slow to download one.

Comment: I see... Unfortunately I'm in the same boat as you at the moment.